# GIMP: Possible to remove middle in picture?

Tags: gimp, crop

As an example, is there an easy way to crop away the o's in the Google logo using Gimp?

The result should then be "Ggle" with a smaller image width than the original because the o's are missing.

[image]

Comment: The linked "duplicate" question does not answer this question.

Comment: I've added an _almost_ solution to this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63279906/1001848

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easiest to copy the elements you want to keep to new layers, then align them and crop.

If you really want to try and do a 'reverse crop', I'd recommend using the `Layer > Liquid Rescale` feature. Add a `Feature Discard Mask` around the elements you wish to disappear, then rescale until they are gone.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the Liquid Rescale. But you forgot to mention it does not ship with GIMP and have to be installed separately (it is a 3rd party plug-in)